# I'm getting error while making an alias system in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making an alias system for my discord bot, and I wanted to say: **"if the user entered the wrong command name or alias then return: invalid command/alias"**, but I'm getting an error:

```
C:\Users\Pooyan\Desktop\PDM Bot Main\events\guild\message.js:16
                    if(!cmd || client.commands.find(a => !a.aliases && !a.aliases.includes(cmd))) return message.channel.send('Invalid command');
                                                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
    at C:\Users\Pooyan\Desktop\PDM Bot Main\events\guild\message.js:16:83
```

My code:

```js
module.exports = async (message, client, Discord) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || 
                    client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));
                    if(!cmd || client.commands.find(a => !a.aliases && !a.aliases.includes(cmd))) return message.channel.send('Invalid command');
}
```

I'm using discord.js v13 and Node.js v16.14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself,
All I needed to do was:

```js
 if(!command) return message.channel.send('Invalid Command/alias');
```

after those two lines,
**It means if command name was not correct, or if the alias was not correct, return "Invalid Command/alias"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Remove the first `!` in your find method, it will fix the error

Comment: I can't use commands if I do this